# nginx ingress rate limiting

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

i am not able to understand one point in the **rate-limiting** of **Nginx ingress**

i was referring to one article regarding rate limiting with nginx ingress : [https://medium.com/titansoft-engineering/rate-limiting-for-your-kubernetes-applications-with-nginx-ingress-2e32721f7f57#:~:text=When%20we%20use%20NGINX%20ingress,configure%20rate%20limits%20with%20annotations.&text=As%20an%20example%20above%2C%20the,qps](https://medium.com/titansoft-engineering/rate-limiting-for-your-kubernetes-applications-with-nginx-ingress-2e32721f7f57#:%7E:text=When%20we%20use%20NGINX%20ingress,configure%20rate%20limits%20with%20annotations.&text=As%20an%20example%20above%2C%20the,qps))%20on%20the%20Hello%20service.

in **limitation section at last**

> It applies to the whole ingress and is not able to configure
> exceptions, eg. when you want to exclude a health check path /healthz
> from your service.

if i am creating two **ingresses** with different **names**, one has path **/hello1** and another **/hello2** both pointing to the **same service backend**.

Now if i am adding rate limiting to only one ingress or path **/hello1** will it affect another? if the same **host or domain** is there ???

**ingress 1** : `example.com/hello1` - rate-limit set

**ingress 2** : `example.com/hello2` no rate limiting

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rate limit will be applied only to that ingress where you specified it. What is basically nginx-ingress doing in the background - it merges rules into 1 huge config, however  they applies to different objects.

e.g 2 different ingresses for same host and diff path.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test1
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'nginx'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: '5'
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /path1
        backend:
          serviceName: service1
          servicePort: 8080
```

and

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test2
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'nginx'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: '10'
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /path2
        backend:
          serviceName: service1
          servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update got it clear now.